# Check all Parse.com fields for existing string before saving?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Parse.com for some storage in my iOS app utilizing both User/password login and Facebook Login. I want it so that once a user logins in through either password or email, it asks them to choose a username, but will only save the string in the custom 'userHandle' field under the Users table if it doesn't already exist. If it does, of course rejection and an error will take place.

Any ideas how I would go about doing this? I assume use some sort of query to check all user's userHandle field to see if the userHandle exists?

Answer (score 0):

Unless they have changed it i am pretty sure Parse's built in User class only allows distinct username values. You can use Parse's Cloud Code so that after a successful save it saves the username value in a userHandle field. That way it already did the checking for the username.

Also you can create a Parse Userquery and set a constraint on the userHandle field for equalTo: the username.

Then call countObjects/countObjectsInBackground.

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to use `.toLowerCase()`, as searches are case-sensitive, and you probably don't care about the case of the username.